# Gmail List API returning all messages when maxResults set to 100

Tags: php, gmail-api

I am working on getting the Gmail List API setup, but for some reason, it returns all 5,000 messages in my inbox even though I have set maxResults to 100. Here is my current code:

```
$pageToken = NULL; 
$messages = array();
$opt_param = array();
do {
    try {
        if ($pageToken) {
            $opt_param['pageToken'] = $pageToken;
            $opt_param['maxResults'] = 100;
            $opt_param['labelIds'] = 'INBOX';
        }
        $messagesResponse = $service->users_messages->listUsersMessages($userId, $opt_param);
        if ($messagesResponse->getMessages()) {
            $messages = array_merge($messages, $messagesResponse->getMessages());
            $pageToken = $messagesResponse->getNextPageToken();
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print 'An error occurred: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
} while ($pageToken);

foreach ($messages as $message) {
    print 'Message with ID: ' . $message->getId() . '<br/>';
}
return $messages;
```

I'm not sure where I am going wrong, but I need to be able to filter down my inbox to the last 100 messages sent.

Comment: That should work... Silly q here, but you're certain $pageToken is not "falsy"? (i.e. that maxResults really gets set?) Also, and this shouldn't make a difference, but maybe try and pass maxResults as a string?

Comment: Yeah, I accidentally didn't add the $pageToken to this, but it is set. I'll update the code now.

Comment: Even on the very first loop?

Comment: No, it was set in the actual code, I just didn't highlight it when I copied the code over to here. It was always in the actual code though. This was all taken from the Gmail API Documentation as well, so not sure what that if statement is for.

Comment: Not sure either but since it starts NULL, that if will return false and so the first call won't have a maxResults set... I'd move both `$opt_param['maxResults'] = 100;` and `$opt_param['labelIds'] = 'INBOX';` out of that "if", so your first call has the same parameters (minus pageToken) than all subsequent calls

Comment: I did think of that too, so I moved them out of the if statement, but it is still returning all 5,000 messages.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135000/discussion-between-macprawn-and-eric-brown).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I just realized, you are getting all messages because even though you are getting them by slices of 100, you are, in the end, doing that in a loop until you get *all* messages in your inbox...

If you only want the first 100, try this instead:

```
$messages = array();
try {
  $opt_param = array(
    'maxResults' => 100,
    'labelIds' => 'INBOX'
  );
  $messagesResponse = $service->users_messages->listUsersMessages($userId, $opt_param);
  $messages = $messagesResponse->getMessages();
} catch (Exception $e) {
  print 'An error occurred: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
if(!empty($messages)) {
  foreach ($messages as $message) {
    print 'Message with ID: ' . $message->getId() . '<br/>';
  }
}

return $messages;
```

So I removed the do/while loop, basically...

Hope this helps!

Comment: There is actually one slight typo, in the if(!(!empty($messages) section, there needs to be another closing parentheses, but other than that, it totally worked. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Right you are - fixed. Glad I could help!